# conda in not installing the new version of a software even though I am using a new environment

Tags: python, installation, conda

I am kind of stuck and confused with conda installation. As per I understand, we can use conda to install multiple versions of software using conda.
I am trying to install the latest version of pennylane software.
I created a new conda environment using the command:

```
conda create --name latest_pennylane
```

After creating the conda env, I activated it using the below command:

```
conda activate latest_pennlane
```

Then I tried installing pennylane in this new environment as below:

```
pip install pennylane
```

I expected a new version to get installed, but nothing got installed. I donot understand why and what I need to do?

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pennylane in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.29.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pennylane-lightning>=0.28 in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (0.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: semantic-version>=2.7 in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: autograd in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pennylane) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: retworkx in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (4.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: autoray>=0.3.1 in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (0.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.24 in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pennylane) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.15.2 in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from autograd->pennylane) (0.18.3)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5,>=4.3 in /home/m992c693/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from networkx->pennylane) (4.4.2)
(latest_pennylane) m992c693@alveo:~/RESEARCH_WORK$ conda install -c pennylane pennylane
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: pennylane
  channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/pennylane
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

It would be really great help if someone can make me understand what I am doing wrong and what I should need to do because when I tried testing the installaton, I am getting the error even though I am using the correct environment.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 from pennylane import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pennylane'
```

Also, I want to ask a question just for my knowledge, when I create a new environment, how the new environment gets python and which version?

Comment: The commands you posted for `conda create` and `conda activate` do not match.  One used the name `latest_pennylane`, and the other used the name `latest_pennlane`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, the output you posted for `pip install pennylane` does not look like you were in a virtualenv.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon. Not sure what I was doing wrong, But When I did 'conda activate latest_pennylane' and then installed 'pip install pennylane', things started working. I am copying the entire terminal for your review.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon. I think, what I did wrong was a typo while activating the environment. Can you answer what all packages get installed especially the python version, when we create a new environment?

Comment: I haven't used `conda`, so I don't know for sure.  I would guess that if you don't specify a version, it defaults to the same version as you currently have.

Comment: A completely new environment won't have anything installed, not even Python. Make sure to always select a Python version, e.g., `conda create -n latest_pennylane python=3.10`. You're likely invoking a `pip` from outside your environment that might be a rather old Python version.

Comment: Thank you @merv for providing me this highly useful information.